# mapReduce with date strange behavior

Tags: mongodb, symfony, mapreduce, doctrine

<<
Hello Guys,

I work with Symfony2 (so Doctrine) and MongoDB. I'm trying to "group by" my results by date.
I found a function to do that but its behavior is strange.

The code:

```
    $qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder('Friends');
    $qb->map(new \MongoCode("function(){
                var date = this.creationDate;
                date.setHours(0);
                date.setMinutes(0);
                date.setSeconds(0);
                day = date.getDate();
                if(day < 10){
                    day = '0'+day;
                }
                month = 1 + date.getMonth();
                if(month < 10){
                    month = '0'+month;
                }
                day = day+'/'+month+'/'+date.getFullYear();
                emit(day, 1);
    }"));
    $qb->reduce(new \MongoCode("function(k, vals) {
                       var count = 0;
                       for(v in vals) {
                            count += 1;
                        };

                      return count;
                    }"
    ));
    $qb->sort("creationDate","desc");
```

The result:

> [timeMillis] => 96 [counts] => Array ( [input] => 2830 [emit] => 2830 [reduce] => 74 [output] => 79 ) [ok] => 1 ) )

The input and th emit are good. But i don't understand why reduce and output are different.
More when i'm trying to do a loop on all results, the total is different.

Thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix replacing map function by

```
 var count = 0;
 vals.forEach(function(v) {
    count += v['count'];
 });

return {count: count};
```

And emit by:

```
 emit(date, { count: 1 });
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I think the **reduce** function should be as

```
$qb->reduce(new \MongoCode("function(k, vals) {
                  return Array.sum(vals);
                }"
));
```